# What does the red dot with three white dots mean in Visual Studio solution files folder, on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, visual-studio, solution-explorer

What does the red circle with the white dots mean, in the solution explorer of Visual Studio for Mac?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means "file is modified".

Apparently the source-control annotations for Solution Explorer icons is still undocumented - even back when it was called Xamarin Studio, see this thread from 2018: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2741/what-do-the-different-icon-annotations-mean

Comment: Thanks for the note and the link.  What is the file modification in comparison to?  In comparison to git? In comparison to some earlier version of the file on your local computer?  Thx

Comment: @PrashantMarathay It indicates that the file on your computer has been changed the same way that `git status` does.